# Solve Integral Equation With Convolution and a constant added

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, convolution

$7t + 8/5 $$\int_0^t \cos (a(t - \tau)) y(\tau) d\tau$$  = y(t)$ , for $ a>10^{50}$

Im sort of confused by working with the constant $a$.

i used convolution theorem and applied laplace, giving it:
$ 7t + 8/5[(s/(s^2 + a^2) Y(s)] = Y(s) $

Comment: Hint: Laplace transforms.

Comment: i know, but the process of simplifying it to apply the inverse laplace that is really bugging me

Comment: You should show us the steps you've already taken to attempt simplification. Click "Edit" above.

Comment: i used convolution theorem and applied laplace, giving it: 7t + 8/5*[(s/(s^2 + a^2) * Y(s)] = Y(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The convolution property says that
$$L\!\left[\int_0^tf(\tau)\,g(t-\tau)\,d\tau\right]=F(s)\,G(s),$$
where
\begin{align*}
L[f(t)]&=F(s)\\
L[g(t)]&=G(s).
\end{align*}
So in your case, that would mean, taking the LT of the entire equation:
\begin{align*}
\frac{7}{s^2}+\frac85\,L[\cos(at)]\,Y(s)&=Y(s)\\
\frac{7}{s^2}+\frac{8\,s\,Y(s)}{s^2+a^2}&=Y(s).
\end{align*}
Solving for $Y(s)$ yields
$$Y(s)=\frac{7(s^2+a^2)}{s^2(s^2-8s+a^2)}.$$
Now can you finish?